# How do call a delete method to run all instances of an index

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I have a method that deletes files off of my ionic 4 App.  I can run a deleteFile() method which deletes individual files.  I Am trying to use a forEach Method to run the through the deleting all files.  But it fails after the first deletion.

html

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let data of list let i = index">
  <ion-card-content>
    <div >
      <div *ngFor="let n of loop let n = index">
        <div class = "linkButtons">
          <ion-button fill="outline" color="blackgreen" (click)=" DeleteAllFiles( )">delete all Photos</ion-button>> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <div>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let doc of documents; index as pos" class="ion-text-wrap">
          <ion-icon name="document" slot="start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-textarea auto-grow="true" ><small>{{ doc.name }}</small></ion-textarea>
          <ion-button slot="end" fill="clear" (click)="deleteFile(doc, pos)">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

The (click)="deleteFile(doc, pos) works fine.

The (click)=" DeleteAllFiles( ) fails after the first deletion.

ts

```
DeleteAllFiles( ): void {
  this.documents.forEach(
    (imgEntry, position ) => this.deleteFile(imgEntry, position ));
}

deleteFile(imgEntry, position) {
  this.documents.splice(position, 1);
  this.storage.get('app_DOCS').then(documents => {
    let arr = JSON.parse(documents);
    console.log("arr ", arr );

    let filtered = arr.filter(name => name != imgEntry.name);
    console.log("filtered", filtered);

    this.storage.set('app_DOCS', JSON.stringify(filtered));
    let correctPath = imgEntry.filePath.substr(0, imgEntry.filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    console.log("correctPath", correctPath);

    this.file.removeFile(correctPath, imgEntry.name).then(res => {
      this.presentToast('File removed.'); // edit later for one toast pop up
      }); 
  }); 
}
```

console.logs

list of docs

```
Documents [
 {
   "name":"UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_icon-144x144.png",
   "path":"ionic://localhost/_app_file_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8772763-A219-407D-92CD-EF5178F0EA9C/Library/NoCloud/UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_icon-144x144.png",
   "filePath":"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8772763-A219-407D-92CD-EF5178F0EA9C/Library/NoCloud/UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_icon-144x144.png"
 },
 {
   "name":"UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_44198511-How-to-Fix-FAL-Rifle-Brass-Strikes.pdf",
   "path":"ionic://localhost/_app_file_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8772763-A219-407D-92CD-EF5178F0EA9C/Library/NoCloud/UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_44198511-How-to-Fix-FAL-Rifle-Brass-Strikes.pdf",
   "filePath":"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8772763-A219-407D-92CD-EF5178F0EA9C/Library/NoCloud/UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_44198511-How-to-Fix-FAL-Rifle-Brass-Strikes.pdf"
 }
]


arr  
  UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_icon-144x144.png,
  UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_44198511-How-to-Fix-FAL-Rifle-Brass-Strikes.pdf

  filtered UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_44198511-How-to-Fix-FAL-Rifle-Brass-Strikes.pdf

  correctPath file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8772763-A219-407D-92CD-EF5178F0EA9C/Library/NoCloud/

arr  
 UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_icon-144x144.png,UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_44198511-How-to-Fix-FAL-Rifle-Brass-Strikes.pdf

 filtered UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_icon-144x144.png

 correctPath file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F8772763-A219-407D-92CD-EF5178F0EA9C/Library/NoCloud/

 imgEntry.name UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_icon-144x144.png
 imgEntry.name UUID_5deb6fae-4d84-41ac-8157-01f9c68e73c5_answerID_155_originalName_44198511-How-to-Fix-FAL-Rifle-Brass-Strikes.pdf
```

Working Code

```
deleteFile(imgEntry, position): Promise<any> {
  console.log("deleteFile selected");
  let request = this.storage.get(this.STORAGE_KEY_DOC);
  console.log("position", position);
  request.then(documents => {
    let arr = JSON.parse(documents);

    this.documents.splice(position);
  // let filtered = arr.filter(name => name != imgEntry.name);

    let correctPath = imgEntry.filePath.substr(0, imgEntry.filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    this.file.removeFile(correctPath,  imgEntry.name).then(res => {
      let resp = JSON.stringify(res);
      console.log("resp", resp);
    });

    let removeDB = this.storage.set(this.STORAGE_KEY_DOC, JSON.stringify(this.documents));
  }).then(( )=> {
  });
  return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "failing" because you are altering the `documents` array whilst you are iterating it.

This is essentially what you have:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.forEach((v, i) => {
  arr.splice(i, 1);
})
console.log(arr);
```

Which boils down to:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.splice(0, 1);
arr.splice(1, 1);
arr.splice(2, 1);
arr.splice(3, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

> If greater than the length of the array, start will be set to the length of the array. In this case, no element will be deleted but the method will behave as an adding function, adding as many element as item[n*] provided.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

To conclude, there is no point to splicing the array as you go. Have your `.then` implementation keep track of the files **successfully** deleted and then splice those after the `.forEach` has completed. You may want to return the promise from your `deleteFile` method so that you can `Promise.all()` it at the end.

---

The example below returns a promise from the deleteFile method. The deleteAll method now maps instead of forEach so that we can store all of the priomises, and then once they are done we will be able to just wipe the documents array. Please not that I updated the below without a compiler, so there may be a couple syntax errors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
DeleteAllFiles( ): void {
  var deleteRequests = this.documents.map((imgEntry, position ) => this.deleteFile(imgEntry, position ));

  Promise.all(deleteRequests).then(() => {
      this.documents = new Arrray();
  });
}

deleteFile(imgEntry, position): Promise<any> {
  var request = this.storage.get('app_DOCS');

  request.then(documents => {
    let arr = JSON.parse(documents);
    console.log("arr ", arr );

    let filtered = arr.filter(name => name != imgEntry.name);
    console.log("filtered", filtered);

    this.storage.set('app_DOCS', JSON.stringify(filtered));
    let correctPath = imgEntry.filePath.substr(0, imgEntry.filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    console.log("correctPath", correctPath);

    this.file.removeFile(correctPath, imgEntry.name).then(res => {
      this.presentToast('File removed.'); // edit later for one toast pop up
      }); 
  }); 

  return request;
}
```

Comment: I am getting a little over my head on this one and could use some help on the .then and the splice after the foreach.  I will be offering a bounty on this when I can in about two days

Comment: @ThomasDegroot No need to offer a bounty reward for this, may as well save it for when you are stuck in future - I will update my answer with an implementation example for you once I finish work in ~11hrs or so.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it

Comment: It still fails at the first doc.  I have included logs to of list of docs and your console logs.  Once again thanks for all you help in this issue I am having

Comment: doing some testing it looks like it fail at this.file.removeFile. Seems to go through the array fine

Comment: Yeah it is weird. Looks like it loops thorough a second time except this.file.removeFile

Comment: I got it working,  I placed the working Code.  I could not have got it done without your answer.

Comment: @ThomasDegroot Very kind of you for the bounty. Glad I was able to help & you got it working!